# Кто с кем сотрудничал?!

Tags: синтаксис

Из Закона, принятого Госдумой 24.10.2014:

> 1. Пропаганда и публичное демонстрирование нацистской атрибутики
>    или символики либо атрибутики или
>    символики, сходных с нацистской
>    атрибутикой или символикой до степени
>    смешения, либо публичное
>    демонстрирование атрибутики или
>    символики экстремистских организаций,
>    атрибутики или символики организаций,
>    сотрудничавших с фашистскими
>    организациями и движениями, и
>    сотрудничающих с международными либо
>    иностранными организациями или их
>    представителями, отрицающими приговор
>    Международного Военного Трибунала
>    (Нюрнбергского Трибунала), либо
>    приговоров национальных, военных или
>    оккупационных трибуналов, основанных
>    на приговоре Международного Военного
>    Трибунала (Нюрнбергского Трибунала), -
>    [влечет и т.д.]

http://asozd2c.duma.gov.ru/addwork/scans.nsf/ID/03FA854663B2B35D43257CA20064A503/$FILE/478164-6.PDF?OpenElement

***Хотелось бы разобраться в синтаксисе и смысле фразы.***

Я правильно понимаю, что часть ***"...публичное демонстрирование ... атрибутики или символики организаций, ... и сотрудничающих с международными либо иностранными организациями или их представителями, отрицающими приговор Международного Военного Трибунала..."*** направлена не на сами организации, что-то там отрицающие, но и на все организации, в чем-то там сотрудничающие с "отрицающими"? В частности, Красный Крест, который вполне себе сотрудничает с отрицающими (холокост, например) организациями?

Answer (score 2):

Ещё одно свидетельство неграмотности депутатов, в данном случае Железняка. Недаром, когда в 2006-м писали ЕГЭ депутаты, только Жириновский написал на 3, остальные на 2.

Он хочет сказать, что наказываются пропаганда и демонстрирование нацистской атрибутики, а не сотрудничество с этими организациями. Красный Крест ничего не пропагандирует, потому не наказывается.

"атрибутики или символики организаций, сотрудничавших с фашистскими организациями и движениями(,) и сотрудничающих с международными либо иностранными организациями" - явная ошибка, запятой не нужно, т.к. это однородные определения - причастные обороты.

Comment: Запятую видел, не стал заострять, ошибка очевидная.  
В отношении "он хочет сказать, что наказываются пропаганда и демонстрирование нацистской атрибутики" - нет. История этого закона такова. Понадобилось запретить "бендеровкую" символику. Поскольку никаким международным трибуналом организации, квалифицируемые в России как "украинские националистические", осуждены не были, была избрана формулировка "организации, сотрудничающие с осужденными Трибуналом...", и тем самым приравняли "бендеровцев" к гитлеровцам.  Так что по части "сотрудничества" всё правильно. Но под эту гребенку де-юре попали все

Comment: Да я поняла, что о бандеровцах. Я о смысле фразы, о том, что подлежащие в предложениях не СОТРУДНИЧЕСТВО, а "Пропаганда и публичное демонстрирование", а во втором пункте - "Изготовление , приобретение, продажа...символики" - это они влекут наказание. А чьей символики - это уже приравнивание этих организаций к нацистским. А разве это неверно? Красный Крест со всеми сотрудничает, но не отрицает названные решения трибуналов, значит,и ненаказуем.

Comment: Секундочку, что именно "разве это неверно"? Если Ваша трактовка, то она противоречит формальной грамматике фразы. Если то, что законотворцы заврались окончательно - это верно. 

"Пропаганда и публичное демонстрирование" - подлежащие. "Согласен". Что из этого следует? Сказуемое - "влечет". "Демонстрация" - дополнение. Пропаганда чего? - символики. Символики какой? 0 организаций, организаций каких? - сотрудничающих. Сотрудничающих с кем? С организациями отрицающими. Все вместе "демонстрация атрибутики организаций, сотрудничающих с организациями отрицающими решения Трибунала".

Comment: Откуда "Демонстрация" - дополнение? Слово "демонстрация" там отсутствует, а "демонстрирование" Вы сами признали подлежащим. Исключаем символику Красного Креста, потому что это не организация, отрицающая решения Нюрнбергского Трибунала или других антинацистских трибуналов и её сотрудничество выражается лишь в милосердной помощи. Слово "сотрудничество", думаю, прозрачно говорит об общих целях. Если ещё уточнять его - это какая же фраза будет?